# Why does running a .NET Core application from VS Code cause an error to occur?

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am trying to run a .NET Core version 1.1 application from inside VS Code version 1.8.1. When I push the F5 button, the console appears at the bottom of the screen. After enabling tracing, I get this output:

> Reading fx resolver directory=[C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr]
>   Considering fxr version=[.]... Considering fxr version=[..]...
>   Considering fxr version=[1.1.0]... Detected latest fxr
>   version=[C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\1.1.0]... Resolved fxr
>   [C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\1.1.0\hostfxr.dll]... Loaded library
>   from C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr\1.1.0\hostfxr.dll Tracing
>   enabled
>   --- Invoked hostfxr [commit hash: 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86] main Own DLL
>   path=[C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.dll] Checking if CoreCLR path
>   exists=[C:\Program Files\dotnet\coreclr.dll] Detecting mode... CoreCLR
>   present in own dir [C:\Program Files\dotnet] and checking if
>   [dotnet.deps.json] file present=[0]
>   --- Executing in split/FX mode... Detected a non-standalone application, expecting app.dll to execute. Application 'build' is not
>   a managed executable.

Also, a bar appears at the top of the screen that says:

> The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 2147516564.

When I click the "show problems" option, a blank problems tab appears that contains the message:

> No problems have been detected in the workspace so far.

Why is VS Code refusing the build the project, and why are there no problem messages? I am only posting this on SO, because Google was not helpful, and because the VS Code GitHub page recommends asking questions here first.

**UPDATE**
This problem was caused by me having put coreclr.dll in C:\Program Files\dotnet. I did this, because of a different problem related to building the app. I thought that, since the output mentions it is looking in this directory, it might be helpful to put this file here. It turns out that this was a very bad idea, as it just complicated the problem! LOL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this error if you have problems in:

- packages - please check if all packages are ok and restored successfully
- core version - check that core installed with correct version
- .net tools - please check if version of .net tools correct.

Can you try visual studio?

Comment: Then it looks like .net tools in project.json

Comment: It seems that this problem was caused by coreclr.dll existing in the C:\Program Files\dotnet directory. When I removed this dll, everything started working.

Comment: Can you please provide all info about how you solved the problem?