# No problems have been detected in the workspace so far

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using and have been usnig Visual Studio to develop Python code.

Previously when I saved a file it would review the code and provide warnings and errors. Now I only get "No problems have been detected in the workspace so far"

I have looked through settings but cannot find anything unchecked that is relevant.

I have intentional errors in the code but get no error messages.

No idea what changed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you may have turned the error squiggles 'off'.
Head to the settings.json file in your workspace (under vscode folder) and change "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles" to "Enabled".
Might Work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can switch the linter, such as from 'pylint' to 'flake8' or other switches. If you don't know how to switch, you can refer to [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_specific-linters).

If it still doesn't work, maybe some extension you installed caused the problem. Try to disable the extensions, and remember to restart the VSCode. You can refer to
[this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19018) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662305/why-does-running-a-net-core-application-from-vs-code-cause-an-error-to-occur) page for some inspire.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the Visual Studio Code from the Developer Command Prompt. Using a Developer Command Prompt (and not a basic/classic/regular console) helps to make sure that all the paths and environment variables are set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can click to Files => Preferences => Setting => Extensions => C/C++ and clicl "v" for all empty place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help].